# Java Stream, Need to update list of list objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Test.java

```
  private String Names;
  private List<InnerList> innerlist = new ArrayList<InnerList>();
```

InnertList.java

```
  private String id;
  private Long x;
  private Long y;
```

```
[class Test {
    Name: test
    innerlist: [class Innerlist{
        id: 1
        x: 0
        y: 0
    }]
}]
```

I have following list:

```
List<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>();
```

Now, I need to update x or y based on two conditions: if Name matches to "Test" & id matches to 1.

I tried writing, but I'm not sure how to update the x/y using setter. I need filter it twice but not sure how to put a condition when `getInnerList` because the condition is on the variable of inner list.

```
list.stream().filter(u->u.getName().equals("Test")).filter(t1->t1.getInnerList());
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are using the wrapper class `Long` instead of  the primitive `long`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `.filter(t1->t1.getInnerList())` doesn't really make sense, since `.filter(...)` expects a predicate as the argument, i.e. a lambda with boolean as the return value. I'm not 100% sure about what you want to achieve, but I assume this would solve your case:

```java
list.stream()
  .filter(u -> "Test".equals(u.getName()))
  .flatMap(u -> u.getInnerList().stream())
  .filter(i -> "1".equals(i.getId()))
  .forEach(i -> {
    // write your setters on `i` here
  })
```

Using `Stream::flatMap` here, we obtain a stream of the elements of `innerList` for the list elements which satisfies the previous filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this solves the issue, using flatMap didn't click.

Comment: Since `id` is declared as a `String` you should use  `i-> i.getId().equals("1")` in your filter.